# Regexp is not working as expected

Tags: php, json, regex, curl

I want to fetch sku of the products,

Please help me to write regexp for this.

Here is my code -

```
$url = "http://api.findify.io/v1.0/store/search?callback=jQuery111206735094679573879_1458022087824&q=154701001&key=5b31ee91-78fa-48e1-9338-1748ca55028e&analytics%5Bkey%5D=5b31ee91-78fa-48e1-9338-1748ca55028e&analytics%5Bvisit%5D=true&analytics%5Buniq%5D=true&analytics%5Burl%5D=http%253A%252F%252Fwww.pandorasoem.com%252Fsearch%2523q%253D154637401&analytics%5Bbaseurl%5D=http%253A%252F%252Fwww.pandorasoem.com%252Fsearch%2523q%253D154637401&analytics%5Bhost%5D=www.pandorasoem.com&analytics%5Bwidth%5D=1920&analytics%5Bheight%5D=1200&analytics%5Binner_width%5D=1438&analytics%5Binner_height%5D=667&analytics%5Bdoc_width%5D=1438&analytics%5Bdoc_height%5D=915&analytics%5Bscroll_x%5D=0&analytics%5Bscroll_y%5D=0&analytics%5Bvisit_id%5D=Ts22zuHHGJRZc3U1&analytics%5Buniq_id%5D=BoeCUKSzgdML6C50&byPage=24&page=0&_=1458022087825";
$ch1= curl_init();
curl_setopt ($ch1, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch1,CURLOPT_VERBOSE,1);
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 1.0.3705; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; Media Center PC 4.0)');
curl_setopt ($ch1, CURLOPT_REFERER,'http://www.google.com');  //just a fake referer
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch1,CURLOPT_POST,0);
//curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 20);
$htmlContent= curl_exec($ch1);
curl_close($ch1);
preg_match_all('/["\']?totalHits["\']?\s*:\s*(\d+)/i', $htmlContent, $count);
print_r($count);    

preg_match_all('/"sku".*:.*"(.*)".*/i', $htmlContent, $sku);
print_r($sku);
```

It showing blank array while fetching sku. It works for Totalhits.

[Update URL](http://api.findify.io/v1.0/store/search?callback=jQuery111206735094679573879_1458022087824&q=154701001&key=5b31ee91-78fa-48e1-9338-1748ca55028e&analytics%5Bkey%5D=5b31ee91-78fa-48e1-9338-1748ca55028e&analytics%5Bvisit%5D=true&analytics%5Buniq%5D=true&analytics%5Burl%5D=http%253A%252F%252Fwww.pandorasoem.com%252Fsearch%2523q%253D154637401&analytics%5Bbaseurl%5D=http%253A%252F%252Fwww.pandorasoem.com%252Fsearch%2523q%253D154637401&analytics%5Bhost%5D=www.pandorasoem.com&analytics%5Bwidth%5D=1920&analytics%5Bheight%5D=1200&analytics%5Binner_width%5D=1438&analytics%5Binner_height%5D=667&analytics%5Bdoc_width%5D=1438&analytics%5Bdoc_height%5D=915&analytics%5Bscroll_x%5D=0&analytics%5Bscroll_y%5D=0&analytics%5Bvisit_id%5D=Ts22zuHHGJRZc3U1&analytics%5Buniq_id%5D=BoeCUKSzgdML6C50&byPage=24&page=0&_=1458022087825)

Comment: Your `sku` response is an array (while your `totalHits` is indeed a number, 3 in this case), please go for a `JSON` parser instead of regexes.

Comment: @Jan I have no idea how to use JSON Parser. Can you please give me example

Comment: This is a `jQuery` response anyway, so here: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the callback parameter from the URL and it will return the proper JSON, then you can convert JSON into an Array or an Object and do whatever you want

**remove** `callback=jQuery111206735094679573879_1458022087824&` from the URL

to convert JSON into an array use `json_decode` ( http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php )

so after you get `$htmlContent` , you can convert it with `$jsonData = json_decode($htmlContent,true);`

you can `print_r` json to check its keys/values,

or if you want to get list of `sku`-s

```
$skus = Array();
foreach($jsonData['data']['hits'] as $hit) {
    $skus[] = $hit['sku'];
}
```

Comment: Json is empty .. I am not getting anything after print_r($jsonData) and also using foreach code. tried to print $skus also. then it shows `PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() `

Comment: have you removed the callback from the URL ?